# Что я вижу в google chrome на вкладке Network?

Tags: html, html5, google-chrome, видео

Была проблема с видео, нужно было его зациклить и играть по кругу. Проблема была решена 2 способами:

1. Менял carentTime на 0.
2. просто в самом теге прописал loop.

Но когда я перехожу на вкладку Network в chrome, то вижу, что когда идет 2, 3 круг видео, то оно вроде как опять буферизируется. С каждым кругом заново.

Из этого следует вопрос:

Правильно ли я понял происходящие, вкладка Network действительно показывает каждый раз новую буферизацию видио, или же эта вкладка отображает что-то другое?

Если я понял все верно, то как сделать, чтоб видео играло по кругу, но при этом не буферезировалось каждый раз при зацикленном возспроизвидении, а делало это только один раз?

Вот код, чтоб было понятно, о чем я толкую:

```html
<video loop autoplay src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

После второго круга видео можно будет наблюдать, как начнет появляться синяя полоска, которая показывает индикацию буферизаци.

Подскажите, как решить данную проблему?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883569/chrome-re-downloads-video-every-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как верно отметили по ссылке, приведенной @Sergey, network показывает загрузку из кэша тоже.

Тут есть три момента, на которые стоит обратить внимание.

Во-первых, кэш может быть отключен чекбоксом `disable cache` вверху панели:

[image: disable cache]

Во-вторых, можно посмотреть, сколько трафика прошло через сеть. На этом же экране ниже:

[image: Network load]

При втором воспроизведении видео эти цифры не увеличиваются.

Ну и в-третьих, для каждого файла виден источник:

[image: File source]

Видно, что в первый раз видео скачалось (4.1Mb), а в последующие — подгрузилось из кэша.